# Git submodules referencing non-existent commits

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to unravel a couple of submodules that have been incorporated into my project.  I'm using VSCode as an editor and until recently, if I made changes to submodule code, it pushed them to their respective repos without issue.  Then a commit file would show up in the main project, which I then pushed so it would update the commit references for the submodules.

There's a couple issues at play:

1. The submodules reference commits that do not exist in their respective repositories
2. There are many changes that have been made to the submodules which are retained locally, but do not appear to have ever made it to their remote repos.

At this point, it's not clear to me how to unravel this and make sure local changes update the submodule repositories.  Calling `git push --recurse-submodules=check` tells me everything is up-to-date, which I suspect isn't telling me what I think it is, anyway.

I have a lot of code changes locally that do not appear to have made it to the remote submodule repos.  Not sure what broke, or how to fix it, but at this point, it looks like I'll have to just completely overwrite the existing submodule repos with the codebase I currently have locally to preserve everything, since git doesn't seem to think there's an issue.